# KendoComboBox устанавиливается в display none

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, kendo

Используется тег `kendoComboBox`. Почему-то при вызове метода `kendoComboBox()` свойство `display` устанавливается в `none`.

```
$('#combo2').kendoComboBox({
            dataTextField: "text",
            dataValueField: "value",
            dataSource: [
                { text: "Cotton", value: "1" },
                { text: "Polyester", value: "2" },
                { text: "Cotton/Polyester", value: "3" },
                { text: "Rib Knit", value: "4" }
            ],
            filter: "contains",
            suggest: true,
            index: 3
        });

<kendo-combobox id="combo2"/>
```

Сначала нормально отрисовывается combobox с пустыми значениями, а вот если применить метод `kendoComboBox()`, сразу же исчезает `<kendoComboBox>` потому что у сгенерированного combobox элемента `display` становится в `none`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Это не ответ, а скорей вопрос к автору:** где что исчезает, я что-то вопроса вообще не пойму:

```js
$('#combo2').kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: [
        { text: "Cotton", value: "1" },
        { text: "Polyester", value: "2" },
        { text: "Cotton/Polyester", value: "3" },
        { text: "Rib Knit", value: "4" }
    ],
    filter: "contains",
    suggest: true,
    index: 3
});
```

```html
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/kendo-ui/content/shared/styles/examples.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<kendo-combobox id="combo2"/>
```